# How to add a custom url to user menu?

Tags: routes, users

I've create a theme for user login page with different style and everything is good.
When a user log in to my site in his profile he can see a user menu and add content link.
I don't want to show /user page when user click on user menu , I want to show /user/% ?
Any advice ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achive it by using [**Pathauto**](https://www.drupal.org/project/pathauto) module

> The Pathauto module automatically generates URL/path aliases for
>   various kinds of content (nodes, taxonomy terms, users) without
>   requiring the user to manually specify the path alias.

Reference

- [DRUPAL – PATHAUTO – MAKING USER FRIENDLY PROFILE URLS](http://www.kiloroot.com/drupal-pathauto-making-user-friendly-profile-urls/)

You can also use **[Menu token](https://www.drupal.org/project/menu_token)** module

> Menu Token module provides tokens, that could be used in title or in
>   path of menu items (links). For example, if you create a menu item
>   with path: "user/[current-user:uid]", the url will be changed "on fly"
>   to: "user/1" (assuming you are user 1).

Comment: Thx , it helped me a lot

Answer (score 0):

You cannot add wildcards to menu item paths. I do not know why you want to do this as it is not neccessarry - when a logged in user clicks on "/user" he gets to his account page.

Comment: yes you're right but when user click on /user ,i do want to go to user/john for example not /user ?

Comment: You could do the following: write custom module, define custom menu path - let's say "my-page" - and add this path to the user menu. In the page callback for this path you define a redirect to the current user's page like "user/[username]"